# Creating a Windows user account with java

Tags: java, privileges, account

Is it possible to create/delete  windows user account and set its privileges to make it admin account , simple user account or guest account using java code ?

Comment: When you have administrative privileges, I think it is possible to do that. However, I don't know how.

Comment: for the admin privileges it is possible when you include a .manifest file to have these privilegs but i think i will choose the the naive way by executing a simple command line .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been already 1 year when i asked this question and i forgot to post the answer. I'm sorry :)

to create a user account we need administrative privileges by wrapping a manifest file with our program. the manifest file must have the same name as the program. this how this file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<security>
<requestedPrivileges>
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable"   uiAccess="False" />
</requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

then we create our userAccount program :

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class UserAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String userName = "foo";

        try {

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net user " + userName + " /add");

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in my case i used the launch4j tool to wrap the manifest with the .jar file and get the program working :)

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up after yourself!

Comment: Thanks, it helps me