# How to Login into Local Windows User Account Using Java

Tags: java, windows

I am running Java code on a remote windows 2012 server. The server will have multiple windows user accounts such as user X, user N, user W and so on.

I want to execute a specific section of code on each account while being logged into Administrator account.

Is it possible to execute a portion of code on another windows user account (i.e, login to account and then log out automatically)?

Note: This is not the same as:

[How to get Windows username in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990038/how-to-get-windows-username-in-java) - as I already know the name of each account or [Creating a Windows user account with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735444/creating-a-windows-user-account-with-java) - as I know how to CREATE a new account but I don't know how to automatically login to account and execute code..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

IBM java community using psexec.exe inside of a java application to perform the action. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/programmatically_connecting_to_remote_systems2?lang=en is the URL hopefully this helps

```
    String psCommand = "<path_of_psexec>/psexec.exe \\\\"+currentServerHostname + " -u " + currentServerUser + " -p " + currentServerPass;
  psCommand = psCommand + " " + commandToRunOnRemoteMachine + " " + parameters;
  String[] cmd = new String[5];
  cmd[0]="cmd.exe";
  cmd[1]="/C";
  cmd[2]=psCommand;
  cmd[3]="";
  cmd[4]="";
  // Run remote command
  File f = new File(getCurrentWorkingDirectory() + "\\lib");
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,f);
```