# How to create a windows local user groups and add users to the local groups using java

Tags: java

Is there any ways using java to create and add users to a windows local groups?, i have a set of users and they need to be added to group created using java ?

Are there any possiblities ?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735444/creating-a-windows-user-account-with-java